# zipline-trader Data ingestion: Issue with datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zipline

The assumption here is that by multiplying 1e9, it will add milliseconds to the datetime objects (I might be wrong). Please look at the code below:

`print(df.index)`

> Index(['2022-04-04T04:00:00Z', '2022-04-05T04:00:00Z'], dtype='object', name='time')

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = pd.to_datetime((df.index * 1e9).astype('int64'), utc = True).tz_convert(NY)
```

> File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3-6-13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alpaca_trade_api/entity.py", line 137, in df
> (df.index * 1e9).astype('int64'), utc = True).tz_convert(NY)
> File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3-6-13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/invalid.py", line 53, in invalid_op
> raise TypeError(f"cannot perform {name} with this index type: {typ}")
> TypeError: cannot perform **mul** with this index type: Index

So it does not allow multiplication with index type. So I do this:

```
   df.index = pd.to_datetime((df.index.astype(np.int64) * 1e9).astype('int64'), utc = True).tz_convert(NY)
```

But the datetime outputs are NaT

> DatetimeIndex(['NaT', 'NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', name='time', freq=None)

This bug is found in entity.py. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow your code because I get an error when I try to do `df.index.astype(np.int64)` "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10"

here's an alternative approach that uses `pd.to_datetime`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['2022-04-04T04:00:00Z', '2022-04-05T04:00:00Z'])
df.index.name = 'time'
print(df.index)
#Index(['2022-04-04T04:00:00Z', '2022-04-05T04:00:00Z'], dtype='object', name='time')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).tz_convert('America/New_York')

print(df.index)
#DatetimeIndex(['2022-04-04 00:00:00-04:00', '2022-04-05 00:00:00-04:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', name='time', freq=None)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include this? I thought you were having trouble converting from string to datetime, but it looks like you have a different question? Can you please edit your question to show what you expecting your output to look like?

Comment: My apologies, my code is missing a line. 
`
                **df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)**
df.index = pd.to_datetime(
                    (df.index.astype(np.int64) * 1e9).astype('int64'), utc = True).tz_convert(NY)
`

The ideas here is that since the Alpaca_api v1 is deprecated, I am using a sample dataset. So I am not sure if my datetime input data is correct. So your code:
`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).tz_convert('America/New_York')` 
works fine.

Comment: However, I am not sure if will be anything else broken in the future. It would be great if you can provide some insights on how should the datetime object look like? Thank you so much

Comment: I have edited my code to show the missing line. I am unable to find out what the output look like since the alpaca api v1 is deprecated. Please refers to this [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZRbaf0641U] to read more about zipline-trader data ingestion

Comment: Or you can explain what is the reason behind **multiplying datetime with 1e9**, I would greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know anything about zipline-trader and I don't know why someone would want to multiply the datetime by 1e9

Comment: No problem mitoRibo, thank you so much for taking your time to reply